# for loop in react to display 20 products at a time

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to create a react app that displays 20 products at a time them a add and them another 20 before another add so I want to do a for loop that displays 20 products. 
I created a for loop but get an error.

this is my render from my component

```
  render() {

  const Prods = () => {
    return (
    <div>
       <div className="row">
            <div className="col-12">
                <button onClick={this.sortPrice}>sort by price lower to higher</button>
                <button onClick={this.sortSize}>sort by size small to big</button>
                <button onClick={this.sortId}>sort by Id</button>  
            </div>  
        </div>
        for (let i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
            {products.map(product =>


            <div key={product.id} className="row">
                <div className="col-3">
                  <p> Price: ${(product.price/100).toFixed(2)}</p>
                </div>

                <div className="col-3">
                  <p style={{fontSize: `${product.size}px`}} > {product.face}</p>
                </div>

            </div> 

            )}
        }
            <p>"~END OF CATALOG~"</p>
      </div>
    );
};

    const { products, isLoading, error } = this.state;
    if (error) {
      return <p>{error.message}</p>;
    }
    if (isLoading) {
      return  <Loading />;
    }
    return (
      <Prods />

    );
  }
}
```

this is my error:

Parsing error: Unexpected token

```
  102 |                         </div>
  103 |                 </div>
> 104 |                 for (let i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
      |                                     ^
  105 |                         {products.map(product =>
```

I tried creating a function outside with an array to do the loop outside the render but got a different error. This is my conponent with the function that has the for loop

```
createDisplay = () => {



    let display = []


    for (let i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
      dislay.push({products.map(product =>


            <div key={product.id} className="row">
                <div className="col-3">
                  <p> Price: ${(product.price/100).toFixed(2)}</p>
                </div>

                <div className="col-3">
                  <p style={{fontSize: `${product.size}px`}} > {product.face}</p>
                </div>
            </div> 

            )})
    }
    return display
  }



  render() {


  const Prods = () => {
    return (
    <div>
       <div className="row">
            <div className="col-12">
                <button onClick={this.sortPrice}>sort by price lower to higher</button>
                <button onClick={this.sortSize}>sort by size small to big</button>
                <button onClick={this.sortId}>sort by Id</button>  
            </div>  
        </div>
        <div>
        {this.createDisplay()}
        </div>
            <p>"~END OF CATALOG~"</p>
      </div>
    );
};

    const { products, isLoading, error } = this.state;
    if (error) {
      return <p>{error.message}</p>;
    }
    if (isLoading) {
      return  <Loading />;
    }
    return (
      <Prods />

    );
  }
}
```

with this I get the next error
Parsing error:

```
Unexpected token, expected ","

  92 |
  93 |     for (let i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
> 94 |       dislay.push({products.map(product =>
     |                            ^
  95 |
  96 |
  97 |                  <div key={product.id} className="row">
```

I am new to react so I am a bit lost.

Comment: You cannot use raw javascript in JSX without surrounding it in curly braces.

Comment: Javascript code inside JSX needs to be wrapped with an extra set of curly brackets.

Comment: also, does products have 20 objects in it? cause your creating these objects 20 times and recreating this display array each time and not *populating* it with 20 items. if that makes sense.

Comment: Protip: rather than using for loops inside of your JSX, prepare your data, then render that in. E.g. something like `const start = this.state.setStart, end = start + this.state.setSize, productSet = products.slice(start, end).map(p => <Product {...p}/>); return <div>{ productSet }</div>;` On that note, having a Product component is probably worth it, if it's more elaborate than a few lines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code in JSX needs to be wrapped in `{}`

```
   { for (let i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
            {products.map(product =>


            <div key={product.id} className="row">
                <div className="col-3">
                  <p> Price: ${(product.price/100).toFixed(2)}</p>
                </div>

                <div className="col-3">
                  <p style={{fontSize: `${product.size}px`}} > {product.face}</p>
                </div>

            </div> 

            )}
        } 
      }
```

for the second one

your trying to push an object with 20 JSX elements:

```
createDisplay = () => {



    let display = [];


    for (let i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        //map returns an array 
        let productElements = products.map(product =>


            <div key={product.id} className="row">
                <div className="col-3">
                  <p> Price: ${(product.price/100).toFixed(2)}</p>
                </div>

                <div className="col-3">
                  <p style={{fontSize: `${product.size}px`}} > {product.face}</p>
                </div>
            </div> 
            );
         display.push(...productElements); //use spread elements 

    }
    return display
  }
```

Also map in a for loop is not what it seems like your trying to do. 
Remove the for loop and just use map. it returns an array of the results of the mapped operations. What your doing is making render take a long time as it creates and populates 20 items for 20 times due to the for loop.

```
{
   products.map(product =>


            <div key={product.id} className="row">
                <div className="col-3">
                  <p> Price: ${(product.price/100).toFixed(2)}</p>
                </div>

                <div className="col-3">
                  <p style={{fontSize: `${product.size}px`}} > {product.face}</p>
                </div>

            </div> 

            )
}
```

You can do everything with the above, no for loop needed.

Comment: ok I get what I am doing it creates and populates 20 items for 20 times due to the for loop. So how would I show only 20 products at a time instead of all the products.

Comment: your trying to essentially page the information. you need to have a state to tell you what "page" of products you are in. the forloop isn't really doing anything. what you can do is splice the products array according to the page state your in and map from there and then when you want to see more products try to update the state and get a new splice of data getting mapped. idrk thats just off the top of my head but thats one thing i would try.

Answer (score 2):

You should accept Kyle's answer but I would break out the array chunking function into a utility method so you can use it elsewhere in your app. Something like:

```
function chunk(array, size) {
  const chunked_arr = [];
  let index = 0;
  while (index < array.length) {
    chunked_arr.push(array.slice(index, size + index));
    index += size;
  }
  return chunked_arr;
}
```